# Datamapper do_postgres gem error: "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQsetdbLogin"

Tags: ruby, postgresql, dyld, ruby-datamapper

I'm trying to run a Sinatra application with Datamapper and a Postgres db locally.
I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.7 and ruby 1.9.2 and each time I launch the application, I get the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQsetdbLogin
    Referenced from: /ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/do_postgres-0.10.5/lib/do_postgres/do_postgres.bundle
    Expected in: flat namespace
```

Does anybody have any idea why such an error?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

probably you use a different version of libpq library than ruby driver expected. Check a version of libpq.

Pavel